# How do I show the JDBC tab in File->Preferences in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

The only tabs that are shown are the ones seen in this screenshot. 
I looked into the logs and see no errors. It does let me open a "JDBC Request" in the TestCase, and put some connection string in, but without being able to select a driver, I don't see how I can use JDBC.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the JDBC Driver Properties tab (in Preferences) is displayed in SoapUI Pro only, not in SoapUI OS(Open Source). In SoapUI OS - You can still add the driver jar to SoapUI_INSTALL_HOME/bin/ext directory, then type the driver class name and connection string manually in the 'JDBC Request' test step to make a JDBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any option to use variables in the connection string (i.e for Username/Password/HostName) that can be saved at project level and changed from their itself. I just need to make multiple connections.